# SwiftUI: Display UIMenuController (or equivalent) on tap?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uimenucontroller

I have a SwiftUI `Text` view in my app, and I would like to display a [UIMenuController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller) or its SwiftUI equivalent whenever I tap on it.  I can capture the tap action successfully by adding an `onTapGesture` block to my View, but I haven't been able to find any examples showing how to display the menu.  Is there a SwiftUI equivalent to `UIMenuController`?  Do I need to create the whole [UIViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) thing for it?

Answer (score -3):

There is a `contextMenu` auxiliary view in SwiftUI

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fave = "?"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Favorite Card Suit")
                .padding()
                .contextMenu {
                    Button("♥️ - Hearts", action: selectHearts)
                    Button("♣️ - Clubs", action: selectClubs)
                    Button("♠️ - Spades", action: selectSpades)
                    Button("♦️ - Diamonds", action: selectDiamonds)
            }

            Text("Your favourite is")
            Text(fave)
        }
    }

    func selectHearts() {
        fave = "♥️"
    }
    func selectClubs() {
        fave = "♣️"
    }
    func selectSpades() {
        fave = "♠️"
    }
    func selectDiamonds() {
        fave = "♦️"
    }
}
```

You don't even have to listen for taps, just a long press brings up a the menu.

[image]

Comment: This is not what was asked 

Comment: People don't read the questions